# SubSonic 3.0 stored procedure generation

Tags: stored-procedures, subsonic3

When using SubSonic 3.0.0.3 and the `StoredProcedures.tt` template, the generated code won't compile and throws an error:

> ... 'DB' does not contain a definition for 'Provider' ...

This is in the calling method for the sproc.

```
StoredProcedure sp = new StoredProcedure("Company_Get", this.Provider);
```

Am I missing something or is there a bug in the 3.0 templates for generating wrappers around stored procedures?

Answer (score 1):

I guess those of us wanting to use v3 of SubSonic are on the bleeding edge.  I needed to generate the code with the context.tt as well.  This corrected my problem.  This is really cool stuff, but the screen casts and the docs are not keeping up with how quickly the product is evolving.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ProcedureParameters Parameters
{
    get
    {
        return sp;
    }
    set
    {
        sp = value;
    }
}

# region "Constructors"

public ExecuteProcedures(int ParameterLength, string ConnectionString):base(true,ConnectionString)
{
    sp = new ProcedureParameters(ParameterLength);
    strConnection = ConnectionString;
}

#endregion

# region "Execute Procedures"

public bool InvokeProcedure(string ProcedureName, SqlTransaction SqlTrn, SqlConnection con)
{
    SqlCommand Sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();

    try
    {
        Sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        Sqlcmd.Connection = con;
        Sqlcmd.Transaction = SqlTrn;

        Sqlcmd.CommandText = ProcedureName;
        Sqlcmd.Parameters.AddRange(sp.ParameterCollection);
        Sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        con.Close();
        SqlTrn.Rollback();
        throw new Exception("Error Occured :-" + e.Message, e);
    }
    finally
    {               
        Sqlcmd.Dispose();
    }
}

public bool InvokeProcedure(string ProcedureName)   
{
    SqlCommand Sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);

    try
    {
        Sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        Sqlcmd.Connection = con;

        Sqlcmd.CommandText = ProcedureName;
        Sqlcmd.Parameters.AddRange(sp.ParameterCollection);

        con.Open();
        Sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {  
        throw new Exception("Error Occured :-" + e.Message, e);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        Sqlcmd.Dispose();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you got the answer to this years ago, but you need to Run All of the ActiveRecord templates, including Struct and Context.